# Spring JPA: Need to join two table with dynamic clauses

Tags: spring, spring-boot, performance, jpa, jpql

Requirement is as below:

Table 1 - Order(ID, **orderId**, **sequence**, reference, valueDate, date)

Table 2 - Audit(AuditId, **orderId**, **sequence**, status, updatedBy, lastUpdatedDateTime)

For each record in ORDER table, there could be one or many rows in AUDIT table.

User is given a search form where he could enter any of the search params including status from audit table.

I need a way to join these two tables with dynamic where clause and get the top row for a given ORDER from AUDIT table.

Something like below:

```
select * from
ORDER t1, AUDIT t2
where t1.orderid = t2.orderId
and t1.sequence = t2.sequence
and t2.status = <userProvidedStatusIfAny>
and t2.lastUpdatedDateTime in (select max(t3.lastUpdatedDateTime) --getting latest record
AUDIT t3 where t1.orderid = t3.orderId
and t1.sequence = t3.sequence)
and t1.valudeDate = <userProvidedDataIfAny> ..... so on
```

Please help

-I cant do this with @Query because i have to form dynamic where clause

-@OneToMany fetches all the records in audit table for given orderId and sequence

-@Formula in ORDER table works but for only one column in select. i need multiple values from AUDIT table

Please help

Comment: Have you tried Jpa Specification API? It allows you to build a conjunction of criterias whether parameters to search by present or not

Comment: What do your entities look like exactly? Assuming Audit has a 1:1 to Order, why are you using the Order->Audit OneToMany (which is expected to represent everything in the DB, not your filter criteria)? You should be able to return the Audit that matches your query "Select audit from Audit audit join audit.order order where audit.lastUpdatedDateTime in (SELECT MAX(ee.lastUpdatedDateTime) FROM Audit a WHERE a.order = audit.order) .. ". For 'dynamic' query building, look into JPA Criteria queries and Spring specifications.